# No module named 'timeout_decorator'

Tags: python, timeout, pytest

I have this weird bug of `No module named 'timeout_decorator'` when trying to `import timeout_decorator`. I have `timeout-decorator==0.4.1` installed in my virtual environment and I am able to import timeout_decorator in python interpreter. But when I ran pytest test.py, it threw this error. I have pytest version `5.4.2`. Anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: You have probably installed `timeout-decorator` for the wrong interpreter. Check whether `pip -V` and `python -V` point to the same correct venv path, then check whether `timeout-decorator` is indeed importbale in that venv (e.g. `python -c "import timeout_decorator; print('ok')"`, then check whether `command -v pytest` points to the same venv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have some problems with my virtual environment and the module probably did not point to the right system path. It works when the python packages are in the system path.